# Filter duplicates in the Lists and Union(or Concat)

Tags: c#, linq

```
   var testfilter = ( from p in test1  where !(from Q in test2 select new {Q.Website,Q.SSN,Q.Class})
                       Contains(new {p.Website,P.SSN,P.Class}) Select P).ToList();

    List<testResults> ResultList = (from R in testfilter  
                                    select new testResults  
                                    {  
                                       Website = R.Website,
                                        SSN = R.SSN,
                                        class = R.class, List1 = 'Yes'  
                                    }.ToList()  
                                   .Union (from Q in test2 
                                    select new testResults    
                                    {   
                                      Website = Q.Website,
                                      SSN = Q.SSN,class = Q.class, Status = Q.Status,
                                      List2 = 'Yes'   
                                   }.ToList();
```

I have to check following conditions in the below lists

1) Few records exists only in **test1** List

2) Few Records exists only in **test2** list

3) Few records exists in both the lists ,if exists in both the lists filter them and display as one record.

The above query works good for records less than 50k, but I have more than 200 k records to be displayed in the grid . How to improve the query using `Except` or other methods ?

Comment: how can u display 200K records in datagrid? pagination should be done.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use distinct something like that not sure if this is the most improved way of solving the problem just a suggestion

```
 List<testResults> distinctResultList = ResultList.Distinct().ToList();
```